# How can I make a fixed top menubar with a changing height in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position, menubar

I would like to have a fixed menubar at the top of my website. (which doesn't move when we scroll). My issue is that this menu bar can have a variable height (one or two (or more) levels depending of the number of items/screen size)

Because the top menu is fixed, I have to add a margin-top for my "real" content after that (or it will begin hidden under the menu), but as the menu height is variable, I can't set a margin-top.

So, is it possible to "force" the content not to be under/over my menubar ? How could I do this ? (I wish not to use javascript for this king of positioning)

Here is the code I am using to test a solution :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

    <style>
        body
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: #575757;
            font: normal 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            background: #cdcdcd;
        }

        #page
        {
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            width:100%;
            max-width:1500px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }

        #mainmenu
        {
            background:#b90014 repeat-x left top;
            position:fixed;
            /*height:28px;*/
            width:100%;
            z-index:100;
            left:0;
            background-image:linear-gradient(#b90014, #d00018);
        }

        #mainmenu p#lastUpdate
        {
            float:right;
            color:#ffffff;
            margin-top:5px;
            margin-right:10px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            margin-left:5px;
        }

        #mainmenu ul
        {
            padding:6px 20px 5px 20px;
            margin:0px;
        }

        #mainmenu ul li
        {
            display: inline;
        }

        #mainmenu ul li a
        {
            color:#ffffff;
            background-color:transparent;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:8px 8px 4px;
        }

        #mainmenu ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul li.active a
        {
            color: #d00018;
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

    <div id="mainmenu">
        <p id="lastUpdate">Last Update : this date</p><ul id="yw0">
            <li><a href="/index.php?r=index">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.php?r=reports">Rapports</a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.php?r=nestedReport">Rapports personnalisés</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/index.php?r=quickReport">Rapports instantannés</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- mainmenu -->

    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentbox">
            HELLO WORLD
        </div>
    </div><!-- content -->

</div><!-- page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

You can apply CSS styles depending on the size of the screen.

Comment: This is probably the way to go if avoiding JS but bear in mind that you will need to have a lot of statements and will need to pick some key height points reset at.  id suggest us a lower z-index for items not in the main bar

Comment: Thank you, I am going to look into that ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in just CSS as it's not able to able detect changes in the page like that.  As stated below you could get somewhere near what you want using css padding but i would suspect it wont be exactly what you want. This is one of the  things JavaScript is designed for.  Id happily be proved wrong though

Comment: The questioner explicitly asked to avoid JS; although the exact behavior he wants may not be possible in CSS something close probably is.

Comment: you are right @EamonNerbonne I just wanted to highlight that it would be difficult without JS but probably didn't state it well.  edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer too ! I mostly don't want to use javascript because I am afraid if I start using javscript for such small things, my page is going to become too "heavy" (maybe not the best translation...) too fast ! I am going to look at the media queries and I'll switch to javascript if this is my only/best option ! (I was actually hoping there was a way to say "content doesn't go under fixed elements" but it doesn't seem to be that way !